# How to add total price in a cart php

Tags: php

hello i am currently doing a project for an assignment to create a website that sells games, so far i have got everything working perfectly up to the point of adding up the totals of the shopping cart. Below is the PHP part of the cart file that displays a game image and game price everytime it gets put into the cart.

The only value that i am getting is 0.

**At the top of this file i have this php file with the query**

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";
session_start();
$memberID = $_SESSION['id']; 


$query = "SELECT rectable.gameID, rectable.gameIMG, rectable.gamePrice, rectable.gameName, basket.quantity FROM rectable INNER JOIN basket 
ON rectable.gameID=basket.gameID";

$results = $connect->query($query);
$numrow = $results->num_rows;
?>
```

Im not sure why this code isnt working:

```
$i = 0;
    while($count < $numrow){
    $i = $gamePrice*$quantity ;
    }
    echo $i;
```

**Cart.php**

```
<?php
$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow)
{
$row = $results -> fetch_assoc();
extract($row);
echo"<div>";
echo"<div class='recommended_games'>";
echo "<img src='images/".$gameIMG."' />";
echo "</div>";


echo '<div class="price_tag">';
echo '<div class="price_tag" name="price" method="POST">£'.$gamePrice. '</div>';
echo'</div>';

echo '<div id="update_form"><form action="updatebasket.php" method="POST" name="updateform">';
echo '<select name="quantity" id="quantity" />';
echo      '<option value="1">1</option>';
echo      '<option value="2">2</option>';
echo      '<option value="3">3</option>';
echo      '<option value="4">4</option>';
echo      '<option value="5">5</option>';
echo      '</select>';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid" id="gameid" />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="update" />';
echo '</form>';
echo '<div class="quantity_update">';
echo '<form action="remove_item.php" method="POST">';
echo     '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid" id="gameid" />';
echo     '<input type="submit" value="Remove Item"  />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';             



echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
echo"</div>";

$count = $count + 1;   

}     
echo '<div id="delete_all">';
echo '<form action="delete_cart.php" method="POST">';
echo '<input id="hide_button" type="submit" value="Clear All"  />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="totalprice">';
echo '<form action="order_items.php" method="POST">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Confirm Items"  />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id=totalprice2>' ;
$i = 0;
while($count < $numrow){
$i = $gamePrice*$quantity ;
}
echo $i; 
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: what value `$numrow` is having ? what are getting in the output? are you getting any error?

Comment: the only value that gets outputted is zero :/

Comment: you have to show where these variables are defined? `$gameprice,$quantity`. post full code

Comment: ive edited my question with my query script not sure if that will help?

Comment: where is `$gameprice` defined bro, does it having 0??

Comment: sorry, im quite new to php but my $gamePrice is just displaying data from my database

Comment: why dont you print all the variables and check what values they have

Comment: i apologize if this is a really stupid question, how can i check this :/ sorry again for the silly question

Comment: just print the gameprice variable and check what value does it have,and same as in while loop ,so you can get clear idea what values does all these variables are having

Answer (score 1):

You are not looping through here:

```
$i = 0;
    while($count < $numrow){
    $i = $gamePrice*$quantity ;
    }
    echo $i;
//add this 
$i++
```

Comment: hmm i tried adding this but no luck for me im afraid :/ it still displays 0 :(

Comment: OK, well you could run another query just getting the values of all uncompleted payments if there is something to identify them in the database. Also, from http://www.php.net/mysql_query This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used